# Derive control points for bezier curve from a bounding box

Tags: calculus, bezier-curve

Given that I start with a bounding box of 4 (x,y) vertices representing the corners. And given that I have 2 of the 3 control points to plot a quadratic bezier curve, how do I derive the 3rd control point such that the resulting bezier curve fits into the bounding box?

[image]

Comment: The solution is not unique. You can start with third point = midpoint and drag it in *any* direction until the curve touches

Comment: This sounds like a brute force approach where an algorithm goes through a whole bunch of possibilities until it finds a third point where t=0. I'm asking for an algebraic way to derive this with a formula such that I could even do it on paper.

Comment: The first comment is not suggesting an algorithm for you to use. It’s telling you that there can not be an algorithm, because your problem has an infinite number of possible answers.